# Automatically add this attribute to the gallery shortcode

Tags: shortcode, gallery, customization

When inserting a gallery it adds the following shortcode:

```
[gallery columns="6" ids="18,150,146,23,147,17,21,20,22"]
```

I would like it to automatically add link="file" as the last attribute, whenever a shortcode is added. Like so:

```
[gallery columns="6" ids="18,150,146,23,147,17,21,20,22" link="file"]
```

Comment: Now that we know what you'd like, can you tell us what you've _tried_? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) I expect you will need to replace the default shortcode with one of your own construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hijack the shortcode handler and set the attribute to a value of your choice. Then call the native callback for this shortcode.

```
add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'file_gallery_shortcode' );

function file_gallery_shortcode( $atts )
{
    $atts['link'] = 'file';
    return gallery_shortcode( $atts );
}
```

Comment: I added this to my functions.php file, but it didn't work. I got this shortcode in the page. 

[gallery ids="144,139,140,138,133,131,127"]

Comment: It doesn’t change the post shortcode, but the attributes the shortcode handler gets.

Comment: @Alexnl Click the [check mark](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G1SEk.png) to mark the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: This one solved the issue. I clicked the checkmark. But I have only tested up to 3.5

I will add a further comment once I test on 3.6

Answer (score 6):

There is a new `shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filter in WordPress `3.6` according to [Mark Jaquith](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2013/04/04/wordpress-36-shortcode-attribute-filter/).

You could use the `shortcode_atts_gallery` filter to force the `link='file'` attribute:

```
add_filter('shortcode_atts_gallery','overwrite_gallery_atts_wpse_95965',10,3);
function overwrite_gallery_atts_wpse_95965($out, $pairs, $atts){
    // force the link='file' gallery shortcode attribute:
    $out['link']='file'; 
    return $out;
}
```

when you have upgraded to `3.6`.

You can check it out in `/wp-includes/shortcodes.php` from the *Core-Trac-Trunk*:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L316

Comment: I'll try this when 3.6 is released at the end of April and I'll leave comment here on my success with it.

Comment: For some reason the link attribute is not passed to shortcode_atts, I filed a ticket [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25405).

Comment: aha, a similar ticket has already been filed [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24979), so hopefully this will work in version 3.7