# Overide Gallery Default Link to Settings

Tags: images, gallery

Is there way to control the gallery default “Link to” setting? Using the `image_default_link_type` filter within a `functions.php` file works on inserting single images into posts but it doesn't seem to have any effect on galleries...

Comment: Hi @Eugene, thank you for such a quick response. I tried the example you provided verbatim on a clean install of 3.6.1 and also with “none” changed to “file” which is the result I was originally after.  I pasted this code at the end of twenty-twelve’s functions file with   no result whatsoever. No warnings with wp-debug enabled either. Did I miss something?
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Have you created a gallery post?

Comment: So you want `[gallery]` to behave like `[gallery link="file"]` ?  Might be a duplicate of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95965/automatically-add-this-attribute-to-the-gallery-shortcode)

Comment: Hey @Eugene, I created the post but never actually clicked the images! How dumb was that? I got hung up on the fact that the “link to” under Gallery Settings still said “Attachment Page”. This works perfectly. 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no legal way to control it. But there is a dirty way to do it... If you select this route, then you will need to :

- clone the standard `gallery_shortcode` function
- add a default value for `$attr['link']` option
- hook your cloned function into `post_gallery` filter

The final result will look like this:

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'wpse8170_gallery_shortcode', 10, 2 );
function wpse8170_gallery_shortcode( $output, $attr ) {
    $post = get_post();

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // override default link settings
    if ( empty(  $attr['link'] ) ) {
        $attr['link'] = 'none'; // set your default value here
    }

    if ( !empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
        // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
        if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) )
            $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
        $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
    }

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr, 'gallery'));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
    $valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
        $itemtag = 'dl';
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
        $captiontag = 'dd';
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
        $icontag = 'dt';

    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
        </style>";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        if ( ! empty( $attr['link'] ) && 'file' === $attr['link'] )
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, false, false );
        elseif ( ! empty( $attr['link'] ) && 'none' === $attr['link'] )
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );
        else
            $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, true, false );

        $image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

        $orientation = '';
        if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) )
            $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
                $image_output
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

There is an easier solution now:

```
function my_gallery_default_type_set_link( $settings ) {
    $settings['galleryDefaults']['link'] = 'file';
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'media_view_settings', 'my_gallery_default_type_set_link');
```

They added a filter to customize this default value (and other values related to the new media upload popup) in WP 4.0 ([trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28693)).

Comment: What file does that even go in?

Comment: Work great! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Old question but still getting search traffic so for everyone else:

You can accomplish what you describe by filtering the gallery shortcode attributes. Also useful if you want to change the default image size, columns, etc.

```
function gallery_should_link_to_files($out, $pairs, $atts)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array( 
    'link' => 'file' 
    ), $atts );
    $out['link'] = $atts['link'];
    return $out;
}
add_filter('shortcode_atts_gallery', 'gallery_should_link_to_files', 10, 3);
```

Edit Jan 2020: As pointed out by @felwithe in comments, this code would go in your `wp-includes/shortcodes.php`, for example. It still works in current Wordrpess !

The filter seems poorly documented in the Codex :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts_gallery

Still, the option to modify the 'link' attribute was added early in 2013 :
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/25665/trunk

Comment: the only example of all the current answers that worked for me. must be inserted e.g. in functions.php of active theme.

Comment: This goes in `wp-includes/shortcodes.php` by the way. Still works in current Wordpress (January 2nd 2021).

Answer (score 5):

Tomas's answer actually contain's the key to change default linking (for Gutenberg). Does not affect already created galleries.

The best way how I was able to implement it, was creating a new edited variation of needed block (gallery), and set it as default. That way the old gallery was replaced by new, edited one.

Register new variation by creating js file in the theme's js folder:

```
// Gallery block
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
   'core/gallery', {
      isDefault: true,
      attributes: {
        linkTo: 'media',
      }
   }
);
// Image block
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
   'core/image', {
      isDefault: true,
      attributes: {
        linkDestination: 'media',
      }
   }
);
```

Enqueue it in fuctions.php

```
function new_gallery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('new-gallery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gallery-var.js',
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom-ready', 'wp-edit-post' )
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'new_gallery' );
```

There is probably a php way to do this too, but for some reason there is only register_block_style mentioned in the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/

I am starting to like gutenberg more and more :)

Comment: Works great, thanks! Use **`file`** instead of `media` to link to the file. Linking to file is sometimes used by Lightbox plugins, to turn the lightbox gallery feature on.

Comment: Also when you do this using plugin instead of template replace `get_template_directory_uri()` with `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Used this and put it in a simple plugin after following @kub1x comment.  Gets the job done, and works fine with the Lightbox plugin I got installed.

Answer (score 3):

This is my working example for WordPress 5.0 (Gutenberg)!

```
function gallery_template_to_posts() {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
    $post_type_object->template = array(
        array( 'core/gallery', array(
            'linkTo' => 'media',
        ) ),
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gallery_template_to_posts' );
```

Comment: [It's also possible to do this for the block editor in JavaScript](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327396/set-default-image-link-target-in-gutenberg-image-block/327400#327400).

Comment: This is exactly what someone else posted claiming it would change the default for single images. It didn't work for either in the current version of WP.

Answer (score 1):

It fact works. As denoted above, in the sidebar it will appear as though the gallery is linking to "Attachment Page". However, once you publish your post and click on the image you will notice that it is in fact linked to the media file.

I took this code a step further and created a plugin. This is functionality that I want to stay site specific instead of theme specific.

To create the plugin I followed the simple instructions on [this page](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users). I created a file named `gallery-link-to-file.php` in the `wp-content/plugins` directory. I then pasted the above code into it and changed `$attr['link'] = 'none';` to `$attr['link'] = 'file';`

I then activated the plugin and it worked like a charm.