# Set default number of columns in gallery

Tags: gallery

Is there a way to set default number of columns in gallery? It is set to 3, and currently I change it manually for every gallery in post I create to 4.

Here are the settings on the right https://codex.wordpress.org/images/c/c7/edit-gallery-drag.png

In codex they say "3 Columns is the default settings, which is ideal for most sites.", but not a word about how to change it. I have only found that I can add it to the shortcode  ( [gallery columns="4"] ), but this isn't what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override many of the Gallery Settings using the [`media_view_settings`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_view_settings/) filter:

```
/**
/* Gallery Default Settings
/* @param Array $settings
/* @return Array $settings
*/
function theme_gallery_defaults( $settings ) {
    $settings['galleryDefaults']['columns'] = 5;
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'media_view_settings', 'theme_gallery_defaults' );
```

To change more settings, the easiest way is to use Developer Tools to inspect the actual field. What you're looking for is an attribute called `data-setting`. Grab that value and use it to override the defaults.

Of course it should be noted that this will not update galleries that already exist. You'll have to run a filter on `the_content` to change it on the fly.

Credits: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169491/7355