# Custom default settings for WP native Gallery Block

Tags: customization, block-editor, gallery, media-settings

I've started with [MarkJ's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/375528/121067) - JavaScript included into the block editor.
I wanted to control more [attributes for gallery](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/core-blocks/#gallery) than `linkTo` — the number of columns, cropping, and **image size**.

```
wp.domReady( function() {
    wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation(
        'core/gallery', {
            isDefault: true,
            attributes: {
                columns: 6,
                imageCrop: false,
                linkTo: 'media',
                sizeSlug: 'thumbnail', // does NOT work in WP 5.9.3
            }
        }
    );
});
```

This snippet does the job partially. In WP editor block settings panel it looks like OK.

[image: WP Gallery Block Settings]

Unfortunately, in fact the size of every image in the gallery remains `large`. Still needs an intervention (change to another size, then back to `thumbnail`).

Is this a `sizeSlug` bug, or
is there a better way to achieve **custom defaults for Gallery Block**?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of what the default is, is incorrect. *"`isDefault` for new blocks"* would be a more accurate interpretation, those existing blocks are *not* this variant.

Think of it this way, if I'm building a row of houses then the plans/blueprints are the default. Changing the plans does not magically transform all the houses that have already been built.

You've told WP when a gallery is created, these are the initial attributes to use when setting this variant. So new gallery blocks would have these attributes, assuming this variant.

Remember, variants are presets, if you create a gallery block that is **not** this variant, give it 6 columns, link to media, no crop, and a thumbnail, then it *becomes* this variant. Default values are *initial* values, not permanent dynamic values that change when you change the defaults.

Likewise, if you create a facebook embed, and modify its attributes to insert a twitter URL, then it becomes a twitter embed block, because they are all variants of `core/embed`. **The attributes determine which variant a block is, not the other way around.**

Comment: Tom, excuse me I haven't mentioned that I don't want transform existing content at all. I want to skip WP defaults to my specific settings at every new insert of the Gallery Block - that's the point.