# Extending Shortcode attributes

Tags: shortcode, customization

I've searched many places and tried many ways for this but no success.

I have a shortcode in my WP Theme like;

```
[recent_posts layout="thumbnails-on-side" columns="4" number_posts="4" offset="" cat_slug="" exclude_cats="" thumbnail="yes" title="no" meta="no" excerpt="no" excerpt_length="35" strip_html="yes" animation_type="0" animation_direction="down" animation_speed="0.1" class="" id=""][/recent_posts]
```

(It is Avada theme's recent posts shortcode). In the core, this shortcode executes

```
WP_Query( $args )
```

function to get posts. But this shortcode cannot be used with Custom Post Types because coders didn't put 'post_type' attribute to shortcode $args (so because of default value is 'posts', shortcode only fetches standard posts).

As a result, i would like to extend/define new extended version of this shortcode for adding 'post_type' attribute **as a variable** (because i would like to use it for many custom post types). How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: I think there is no way. You have to ask theme developers to add `post_type` option or make possible to add custom arguments to the shortcode.

Comment: Maybe you could add code examples to your question and make it independent of your paid theme (third party plugins/themes are off topic)?

Comment: @birgire Actually you're right but i don't know is this breaks the license because code seems to be coded by theme authors in custom way so i decided to try Pieter's second advise. But additionally, I'll ask to authors for code sharing, if they said no problem, I'll update question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to give you an exact answer. There is the `shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filter that was introduced in Wordpress 3.6. All attributes is run through this filter. It has to be noted that the `$shortcode` parameter needs to be set in [`shortcode_atts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts). I haven't seen shortcodes yet that has this parameter set though.

Your problem here is actually bigger that just the attributes as you will need to add the attribute and the `post_type` parameter to your query arguments. If the author did not supply a custom filter for the query arguments, then you are at a dead end street.

IMO, you have two choices here

- Contact the theme author and ask him to at the relevant code to the shortcode in his next update. I don't think that he/she will have an issue as this adds value to the shortcode
- Create a child theme and copy the shortcode to the child theme. Modify the shortcode as needed, and remember to change the function name and shortcode name accordingly. This way you will have a shortcode that fits your needs

Comment: second way seems to be easier for now because i don't know when next version will be released. Thanks for help.

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's just an addition to the answer by @PieterGoosen.

There are few methods how one could modify the *post type* of `WP_Query`, that's inside a shortcode. Let's assume it's `[recent_posts]`.

**Method A)** If the shortcode uses the third parameter of the `shortcode_atts()` (as @PieterGoosen mentioned) for example `wpse`, then:

```
/**
 * Method A: Using the shortcode_atts_$shortcode filter + pre_get_posts action
 */

add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_wpse', function ( $out, $pairs, $atts )
{
    if( isset( $atts['post_type'] ) && $post_type = $atts['post_type'] )
    {
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) use ( $post_type )
        {
            static $activated = false;
            if( ! $activated )
            {
                $q->set( 'post_type', santize_key( $post_type ) );
                $activated = true;
            }
        }
    }       
    return $out;
} );
```

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95971/26350) you can see my other answer on how to use this filter.

**Method B)** Else, we can re-register the shortcode with a new callback.

Change it from `old_recent_posts` to `new_recent_posts`:

```
/**
 * Method B: Re-register the shortcode
 */

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function()
{
    if( function_exists( 'old_recent_posts' ) )
    {
        remove_shortcode( 'recent_posts', 'old_recent_posts' );
        add_shortcode(    'recent_posts', 'new_recent_posts' );
    }

} );

function new_recent_posts( $atts = [], $content = '' )
{
    if( isset( $atts['post_type'] ) && $post_type = $atts['post_type'] )
    {
        add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) use ( $post_type )
        {
            static $activated = false;
            if( ! $activated )
            {
                $q->set( 'post_type', santize_key( $post_type ) );
                $activated = true;
            }
        }
    }       
    return old_recent_posts( $atts = [], $content = '' );
}
```

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95985/26350) you can see how @toscho replaces the shortcode callback, in the same question as my linked answer above.

Note that I didn't test this, but hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Nice extention :-)

Comment: Thanks @PieterGoosen. I think you're right about few themes using the third parameter of the `shortcode_atts()` function. Many of them also use the `extract` method and I'm afraid that some even don't  bother to sanitize the user input ;-)

Comment: Let me try second one, because I've tried your first way ( http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95971/26350 ) but no success and i didn't see any shortcode_atts support in code. Thanks..

Comment: Hmmm, another problem is this shortcode is coded by OOP technique so i couldn't access via function name. You can find logic here : 'class FusionSC_RecentPosts' wraps the shortcode and construction starts with 'public function __construct() {'
After than, 'add_shortcode( "recent_posts", array( $this, "render" ) );' so render function executing to show the result/execute the WPQuery function.
How can i access this function from 'functions.php' to extend it? Thanks again.

Comment: How is `FusionSC_RecentPosts` instantiated? Is the instance globally accessable? You might also try  `do_shortcode( '[recent_posts ...]' )` instead of using the old shortcode callback. @Alper

Comment: `class FusionSC_RecentPosts{
All the code of shortcode are here
} new FusionSC_RecentPosts();`

Comment: can i use `FusionSC_RecentPosts::render` as `old_recent_posts`?

Comment: ahh, so it's like `new FusionSC_RecentPosts();` but not something like `$some_object = new FusionSC_RecentPosts()`. The `render()` method is not static so you can't do that. You could try to instantiate your own instance inside the shortcode callback and see if that works. @Alper